# What is the difference between Filenet 4.5 and Filenet 5

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet

Can someone please summarize what are the differences between FileNet P8 4.5 and FileNet P8 5.0?

Comment: Can you be more accurate? 5.1? 5.2?, Java APIs, deployment, installation, developing, Workplace, WorkplaceXT, Content Search... See on Ian Wilsons the releases http://ian-wilson.co.uk/archives/422/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously PE (Process Engine) and CE (Process Engine) are separated now the file-net 5.2 is a single server which contains both in one server.

Answer (score 1):

1. In FileNet 4.5, Process Engine was a C++ component, It is a J2EE based component in Version 5 Onwards. So it could be installed even in Linux platforms version 5.0 onwards, which was not possible before.
2. With V5.0 onwards we can use some powerful new FileNet solutions such as Case manager.
3. Apart from major platform Engine architecture change there are various other changes as well. Please refer following link for more details.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.0.0/com.ibm.p8.relnotes.doc/wn_p8501.htm

Answer (score 0):

And in FileNet 5.2 the process engine is integrated into the content engine ear, so a single server for content engine and process engine.

Answer (score -1):

Main difference is that Process is running as J2EE application.